# Property 'env' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

Recently i begin a project using vue.js and vite, everything run normal when using `npm run dev` but when `npm run build` its keep give me error `Property 'env' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'.ts(2339)`

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    }
 ]
})

// test access to Vite environment variable
console.log(import.meta.env.BASE_URL);

export default router
```

Here is my `env.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: Record<string, string>;
}
```

here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```

I have added compiler options, for vite/client but still resulting the same, any guidance or tips will be really useful. I appreciate any response.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same trouble on my project.
I'm just copy your env.d.ts content fix it using copilot to:

`/// <reference types="vite/client" />
interface ImportMeta {
    readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}`

and everything works now